# yii2 routes double slash

Tags: routes, yii2, yii-url-manager

I'm rewriting the back-end of a mobile APP
and for retro-compatibility I need to serve URL like this one

http://example.com/yii2app//sc4m/scPictureServlet/Pictures/clogo/5/ice2014.png/W/150

the problem I receive from the App URL with double slashes //
code on the app cannot be changed

I have tried to configure the route to serve these links with a controller but I receive a 404 link posted

this address instead (with no double slash is working fine)
http://example.com/yii2app/sc4m/scPictureServlet/Pictures/clogo/5/ice2014.png/W/150

how can I setup urlManager routes to serve also double slashes address ?

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '//sc4m/scPictureServlet/<category:\w+>/<subcategory:\w+>/<subfolderid:\d+>/<picname:\w.+>/W/<width:\d+>' => 'sc4m/pictureServlet',
            '/sc4m/scPictureServlet/<category:\w+>/<subcategory:\w+>/<subfolderid:\d+>/<picname:\w.+>/W/<width:\d+>' => 'sc4m/pictureServlet',

        ],
```

thank you very much in advance
alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize your URL in the index.php !

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=str_replace('//','/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This is to be added before the `require('yii.php');`